# How do I position this button element beside the text and header?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble placing this button beside the paragraph element. I don't want it under it, rather I want it placed on the same line.

```
<div class="up">
  <div class="ban">
    <div class="act">
      <h2>Join The Action</h2> 
      <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
      <button>Join Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing the flex-direction to row, however, that just leaves me with all three elements on the same line, and not the header on top of the paragraph element, with the button on the same line.

```
.up {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 19vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.ban {
  width: 1150px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color:  red;
  color: white;
}

.act {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:flex-start;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

.act p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.act button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that the question title differs from your opening sentence. Do you want the button next to the `p` or next to the `h2` heading and `p`?

Answer (score 1):

ralph.m's answer saying to have the `h2` heading fill the row made me think of using Grid and having `h2` span two columns. Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.act {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1em;
  padding: 0 50px 50px;
}

.act h2 {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}

.act button {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```css
.up {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* height: 19vh; */
  /* align-items: center; */
}

.ban {
  /* width: 1150px; */
  /* height: 250px; */
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color:  red;
  color: white;
}

.act {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  /* align-items:flex-start; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1em;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 50px 50px;
}

.act h2 {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}

.act p {
  /* padding: 10px 0; */
  margin: 0;
}

.act button {
  width: max-content;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* margin-top: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="up">

  <div class="ban">

    <div class="act">
      <h2>Join The Action</h2>
      <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
      <button>Join Up</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Grid definitely is a nicer solution for this. Seems to give a lot more flexibility without the extra HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can group `<h2>` and `<p>` in a single div like below

```
 <div class="group">
    <h2>Join The Action</h2> 
    <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
  </div>
```

Note: This `<div>` should still be inside your act div like below.

```
    <div class="act">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Join The Action</h2> 
    <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
  </div>
  <button>Join Up</button>
</div>
```

Also adjust your css for `.act` to set your `flex-drection` to row and justify your content as space-between.

```
.act {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `p` and `button` inside a `div` and apply flexbox to that container.

(I realized that Shodipo Ayomide posted a similar answer as I was composing this one. However, you said you wanted the button next to the paragraph.)

```css
.up {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* height: 19vh; */
  /* align-items: center; */
}

.ban {
  /* width: 1150px; */
  /* height: 250px; */
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color:  red;
  color: white;
}

.act {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  /* align-items:flex-start; */
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

.act p {
  /* padding: 10px 0; */
  margin: 0;
}

.act button {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  /* margin-top: 10px; */
}


.join {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">

  <div class="ban">

    <div class="act">
      <h2>Join The Action</h2>
      <div class="join">
        <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
        <button>Join Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra containers when using flex. You can instead set the heading to fill the row.

```css
.up {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 19vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.ban {
  width: 1150px;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color:  red;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.act {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items:flex-start;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.act p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.act button {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <div class="ban">
    <div class="act">
      <h2>Join The Action</h2> 
      <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
      <button>Join Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought it sounded like a good idea until I realized that `flex-wrap: wrap` causes `button` to wrap to the next row in narrow viewports before word-wrapping is applied to the text inside `p`

Comment: True. Depends on what the OP wants, I guess!